# Best way to keep an Earnings Record ensuring performance and maintainability

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I'm trying to keep a record of the earnings of the users of my website and I'm stuck at which of the following designs is best regarding performance and overall usability:

**• First way:**

In this way a single database will be created containing a table for each year. Each table will have 13 columns, the user ID and the 12 months. The value for each field will be a stringified array with the values of all the days of the month, like so: **`[12.5, 28.3, 9.75, ...]`**.

**Code:**

```
-- Create a database to keep record of the earnings of all users.
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `Earnings_Record`;

-- Create a table for each year containing 13 columns, the user ID and the 12 months.
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Earnings_Record`.`Earnings_2017` (
    `ID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `January` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    `February` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    ...
    `December` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

---

**• Second way:**

In this way multiple databases will be created, one for each year, containing a table for each month. Each table will have 28-31 + 1 columns, the user ID and the 28-31 days. The value for each field will be a decimal, like so: **`12.5`**.

**Code:**

```
-- Create a database to keep record of the earnings of all users for 2017.
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `Earnings_2017`;

-- Create a table for each month with 28-31 + 1 columns, the user ID and the 28-31 days.
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Earnings_2017`.`January` (
    `ID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `Day 1` DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL,
    `Day 2` DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL,
    ...
    `Day 31` DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

---

Since the website will hopefully be running for 5-10 years, which is the best way to design this when it comes to overall performance and long-term maintainability?

*(One thing to keep in mind is that the earnings of each user will be updated multiple times every day for active users)*

Answer (score 1):

Third way:

Create a single database.  Create a single table for each entity:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS Earnings_Record;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Earnings_Record.Users (
    UsersId INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    . . .
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Earnings_Record.Earnings (
    EarningsID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    UserId INT NOT NULL,
    EarningsDate DATE,
    Amount DECIMAL(10, 2)  -- or whatever
    CONSTRAINT fk_Earnings_UserId FOREIGN KEY (UserId) REFERENCES Users(UserId)
) ;
```

Simple.  Easy-to-query.  Just what you need.  This is the SQL way to represent data.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The database I'm talking about is an "expansion" and I want it to save the earnings and make specific calculations like projected earnings, growth over the last period etc. The users are saved in my existent 'main' database and I will match the data to each of them by using the ID.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer this - but any solution that requires multiple databases or tables is probably not maintainable, or scalable, or fast.

I really don't understand your business domain - you say you want to maintain earnings per user, but your tables don't have any reference to a user.

To design the database, it would really help to understand typical queries - do you want to find out total earnings for a period? Do you want to find days with high and/or low earnings? Do you want to aggregate earnings over a group of dates, e.g. "every monday"?

I'd start with:

```
table earnings
-------------
earnings_date (date) (pk)
earnings_amount (decimal 10,2)
```

Comment: The dates are not important. I want to save them, so that I can calculate statistics such as projected earnings for month/term/year, growth over last period etc. The users are already saved in a different database and I will match the data to them using the ID.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple databases -- **NO**

Splaying the months across 12 columns -- **NO**

Stringifying -- Only if you never need MySQL to filter on the data or do arithmetic on the data.

All of these are discussed in various ways in this forum.

There is no problem having thousands, even millions, of rows in a table.  The other approaches are headache-causers.